# SQLite Objective C Database Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

Could anyone help me with creating a SQLite Database that can "Add", "Update", "View" and "Delete" records on a Table View?

I am very new to this and I need some help from you guys

The image below will show you a rough idea of what I am trying to create

Inside the Title I would like to display the "Classroom" & "Day, (eg. Monday)"

And inside the subtitle I would like to display the start time & end time

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: see this link have good explanation of sqllite step by step https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/iOSCuriosity/Sqlite-CRUD-expanding-row-heights/tree/master/Task1103

Comment: @ravi.p hi i have seen that and the code is quite backdated do you know if there is something more newly created cos i am using xcode 8

Comment: @EzekielTan it is old tutorial but if you follow proper step then you get your desire out put and tableview and sqllite was old concept so now a days nobody posts blogs about it they all write new things